# Why doesn't holoviews show colors?

Tags: python-3.x, graph-visualization, holoviews

I am trying to reproduce a simple example from holoviews. I am running `bokeh Version: 0.12.11` and `holoviews Version: 1.9.1`. 
Here is how it goes.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')

macro_df = pd.read_csv('http://assets.holoviews.org/macro.csv', '\t')
key_dimensions   = [('year', 'Year'), ('country', 'Country')]
value_dimensions = [('unem', 'Unemployment'), ('capmob', 'Capital Mobility'),
                    ('gdp', 'GDP Growth'), ('trade', 'Trade')]
macro = hv.Table(macro_df, key_dimensions, value_dimensions)

%%opts Scatter [width=700 height=400 scaling_method='width' scaling_factor=2 size_index=2 show_grid=True] 
%%opts Scatter (color=Cycle('Category20') line_color='k')
%%opts NdOverlay [legend_position='left' show_frame=False]
gdp_unem_scatter = macro.to.scatter('Year', ['GDP Growth', 'Unemployment'])
gdp_unem_scatter.overlay('Country')
```

This is my result:
[image]

No matter what I do, I can't color the categories as depicted in the example [here](http://holoviews.org/gallery/demos/bokeh/scatter_economic.html). Even if I define my own `color`...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you report the versions of HoloViews and Bokeh you are using? It seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Should have done that from begin with. I am running `holoviews Version: 1.9.1` and `bokeh Version: 0.12.11`. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Works fine for me too, putting everything up to %% in one Jupyter notebook cell and the rest in a second cell.